# Bode plot acting weird with specific op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, bode-plot

Hello why is the behavior of this op-amp so weird (OP177).I simulated another op-amp(uA741) with the same biasing and the bode plot looks fine(still i dont get the 80dB amplification i would like, yea any advice on that ?).[image: OP177]

[image: uA741]
[image: Schematic]

op177-first image
uA741-second image

Comment: Why capacitors are in series with +Vcc and -Vcc pins of Opamps?!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Brian those are both gain plots thats the problem i am trying to describe.

Comment: then Hamid has it...

Comment: Thank you both! That fixed it  but can i get an explanation why that is the wrong way to do it.Also any tips about reaching 80dB gain ?

Comment: @HamidR.Tanhaei They are decoupling caps meant for decoupling the supply from the circuit. ;)

Comment: Decoupling caps go in PARALLEL, i.e. from V+ to 0V and V- to 0V, not in series.